# Java Stream : multiple grouping

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I can group by one field but i want to group by both together

```
//persons grouped by gender
Map<String, Long> personsGroupedByGender = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender, Collectors.counting()));

//persons grouped by age
Map<Int, Long> personsGroupedByAge = persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge, Collectors.counting()));

//persons grouped by gender and age 

    ???
```

Comment: `.getAge()` returns a String?

Comment: I corrrected that one

Comment: @Marvy may be `Map<Integer, Long>`? Probably a typo.

Answer (score 7):

You can group twice, the result will be what you expect, but in a slightly different wrapping.

```
persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender,  
              Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge, Collectors.counting())));
```

Comment: @Marvy if it helped might as well accept it. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to create a helper class which represents your grouping key (gender and age, in this case), with appropriate `equals` and `hashCode` implementations.  You can then create a mapper function from your `Person` to this key, and group by that.

Comment: that's not a bad suggestion overall and while I did not downvote - you probably got it because you should have showed some code also...

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair;
```

```
Map<Pair<String, String>, Long> personsGroupedByGenderAge = persons.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
         person -> Pair.of(person.getGender, person.getAge),
         Collectors.counting()));
```